# How to caculate number of words in a page

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word

How to caculate number of words in a page of word document
I need the VB code for this action that will allow me to automate calculation of word count that will be place at the footer of each page

I tries searching for solution but no luck

Comment: Well, you could get really close by counting spaces. but it might be a bit more difficult if you need exact number

Comment: Wait, no there is a words.count property: [SEE HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.words.count)

Comment: @CameronCritchlow Word VBA most certainly can count words on pages. And it even has an (unreliable) .Words.Count property. What have you been smoking?

Comment: @macropod What? no! I'm saying there **IS** a words.count property... although in trying to figure out to add each page's word count to a sheet I **did** learn about it's unreliability. It seems about as useful as counting spaces. I got as far as inserting them into each page (at the end, not hidden) when I realized it was counting: "Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World" as 10 words.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're prepared to insert 'Next Page' Section breaks between your pages, you cannot have the individual page counts in the page headers or footers. The following code does the required calculations and inserts the page counts as hidden text at the top of each page's body text. Content in page headers, footers, footnotes, endnotes & textboxes is ignored.

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim p As Long, w As Long, Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument
  For p = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages) To 1 Step -1
    Set Rng = .GoTo(What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=p).GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page")
    With Rng
      w = .ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticWords)
      .Collapse wdCollapseStart
      .Text = "[" & w & "]"
      .Font.Hidden = True
    End With
  Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Do note that I have not used the .Words.Count property as that is unreliable.

Comment: I almost never get into VBA with ms word. I find trying to figure out how to navigate to reference points very difficult. This is quite clean.